# How to dynamically create form.Fields from Stores in ExtJS 4

Tags: forms, extjs4, store

I have two stores, `Assessor.store.Question` and `Assessor.store.Choice`, along with their respective Models and Proxies. The load data from the server as intended. I also have a Panel, `Assessor.view.QuizCards`, with a "card" layout. This works fine and I can create dummy cards, `Assessor.view.QuestionCard`, and navigate through them fine using the `Assessor.controller.Quiz` controller.

What I need help with is programatically populating my `QuizCards` panel with questions and choices from the `Questions` and `Choices` stores. I've tried just about everything I can think of based on the docs and have had absolutely no success.

Specifically, I want the `"value"` of the `"displayfield"` on a `QuestionCard` to be the `"text"` property from the `Question` store/model. The `"boxlabel"` values in the `"radiogroup"` should come from the associated `Choice` store/model.

The detailed code is below. Thanks for any guidance you can provide.

```
Ext.define('Assessor.controller.Quiz', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    itemId: 'quizcontroller',
    models: ['Question', 'Choice'],
    stores: ['Question', 'Choice'],
    views: ['QuestionCard'],
// Constants, kinda
    NUM_QUESTIONS: 4,
// Custom Functions
    /**
     * create store instances
     */
    createStores: function(){
        if (Ext.getStore('questionstore') == null) {
            var qs = Ext.create('Assessor.store.Question');
            qs.load();
        };
        if (Ext.getStore('choicestore') == null) {
            var cs = Ext.create('Assessor.store.Choice');
            cs.load();
        };
    }, //end createStores
    /**
     * update buttons
     */
    updateButtons: function(){
        var index = this.getCardIndex();
        var nb = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#nextbutton')[0];
        var pb = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#prevbutton')[0];
        var fb = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#finishbutton')[0];
        if (index<this.NUM_QUESTIONS) {
            nb.enable();
            fb.disable();
        } else {
            nb.disable();
            fb.enable();
        };
        if (index>0){
            pb.enable();
        } else {
            pb.disable();
        };
    }, //end updateButtons
    /**
     * get active question card index
     */
    getCardIndex: function(){
        return (Ext.ComponentQuery.query('quizcards')[0].getLayout().activeItem.itemId.split('-')[1]);
    },
    /**
     * set active question card index
     */
    setCardIndex: function(index){
        Ext.ComponentQuery.query('quizcards')[0].getLayout().setActiveItem('questioncard-'+index);
    },
    /**
     * start the quiz
     */
    startQuiz: function(args) {
        this.createQuestionCards();
        var sb = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#startbutton')[0];
        sb.disable();
        this.updateButtons();
    },
    /**
     * create the UI cards with questions from server.
     */
    createQuestionCards: function() {
        var qc =  Ext.ComponentQuery.query('quizcards')[0];
        for (i=0; i<this.NUM_QUESTIONS; i++) {
            card = Ext.create('Assessor.view.QuestionCard');
            card.itemId = 'questioncard-' + i.toString();
            qc.add(card);
        };
        this.updateButtons();
    },
    /**
     * finishQuiz -- finishes and scores the quiz
     * @param {Object} args
     */
    finishQuiz: function(args) {
        this.localState.set('quizFinished', true);
    },
    //
    nextQuestion: function(args) {
        console.log('\nnextQuestion');
        var cardlayout = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('quizcards')[0].getLayout();
        var activeIndex = cardlayout.activeItem.itemId.split('-')[1];
        console.log(activeIndex);
        if (activeIndex < this.NUM_QUESTIONS) {
            activeIndex++;
            this.setCardIndex(activeIndex);
        };
        this.updateButtons();
    },
    //
    prevQuestion: function(args) {
        console.log('\nprevQuestion');
        var cardlayout = Ext.ComponentQuery.query('quizcards')[0].getLayout();
        var activeIndex = cardlayout.activeItem.itemId.split('-')[1];
        console.log(activeIndex);
        if (activeIndex > 0) {
            activeIndex--;
            this.setCardIndex(activeIndex);
        };
        this.updateButtons();
    },
     //
     init: function(){
         this.control({
            '#nextbutton': {
                click: this.nextQuestion
            },
            '#prevbutton': {
                click: this.prevQuestion
            },
            '#startbutton': {
                click: this.startQuiz
            },
            '#finishbutton': {
                click: this.finishQuiz
            },
        })
    }
})

Ext.define('Assessor.view.QuizCards', {
    extend: 'Ext.panel.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.quizcards',
    itemId: 'quizcards',
    layout: 'card',
    activeItem: 0,
    items: []
})

Ext.define('Assessor.view.QuestionCard', {
    extend: 'Ext.form.Panel',
    alias: 'widget.questioncard',
    layout: 'anchor',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'displayfield',
        itemId: 'questionfield',
        name: 'questionfield',
        fieldLabel: 'Question',
        value: ''
    }, {
        xtype: 'radiogroup',
        itemId: 'choicegroup',
        columns: 1,
        vertical: true,
        items: [{
            boxLabel: '',
            name: 'choice',
            value: 1
        }, {
            boxLabel: (100*Math.random()),
            name: 'choice',
            value: 2
        }, {
            boxLabel: (100*Math.random()),
            name: 'choice',
            value: 3
        }]
    }]
})

Ext.define('Assessor.store.Question', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    autoLoad: true,
    autoSync: true,
    model: 'Assessor.model.Question',
    storeId: 'questionstore'
})

Ext.define('Assessor.model.Question', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    fields: [
        {name: 'id', type: 'int'},
        {name: 'text', type: 'string'},
        {name: 'resource_uri', type: 'string'}
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'rest',
        url: '/api/v1/question/',
        headers: {
            'accept':'application/json',
            'content-type':'application/json'
        },
        noCache: false,
        reader: {
            type: 'json',
            root: 'objects',
            idAttribute: 'id'
        },
        writer: {
            type: 'json'
        }
    }
})
```

Choice model and store are similar, I'll post them if needed. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I would suggest for the start is to make `Assessor.view.QuestionCard` more smart. I would rewrite `initComponent` there and pass record from the store during construction. This way you would have all logic for creating specific UI elements inside `Assessor.view.QuestionCard` and would call it something like that:

```
card = Ext.create('Assessor.view.QuestionCard', {
   questionRecord: rec,
   lastQuestion: true/false...
   ... whatever else you need 
})
```

Comment: I've tried that, I think. My problem is that I cannot seem to get it to access the store. If I do something like `qs = Ext.create('Assessor.store.Question'); qs.getAt(0).data['text']` in the FireBug console, everything works. If I try to access the store, either newly created or fetched via `Ext.getStore`, inside a loop I always get an error: `qs.getAt(i) is undefined`.

Comment: 1. Don't create a store manually. Ext.getStore is right way to do this.

Comment: 2. Wait till store is loaded (load() is async procedure, so might not have store loaded right after you get it.

Comment: Well, as you can see I check to see if the store got registered: `if (Ext.getStore('questionstore') == null) { var qs = Ext.create('Assessor.store.Question'); qs.load(); };`. It never seems to get created by the controller.

Comment: Why are you using separate storeid? If you have stores: ['Question'], you should use Ext.getStore('Question')

Comment: Holy s##t! I've been fighting with this for a couple of weeks on and off. Somehow, that part of the documentation missed my brain. I really appreciate the correction. :)